# How can I simplify this if-else into one statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

How can I simplify the following code to one line (without the `if-else` statement)?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    boolean result;
    boolean a = false;
    boolean b = false;
    boolean isEmpty = false;
    if (a) {
        result = isEmpty && !b;
        System.out.println("if  " + (isEmpty && !b));
    } else {
        System.out.println("else    " + !b);
        result = !b;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: your code won't go into the `if` (`a` is set to `false`). Are you sure that  this is the correct code?

Comment: something like `result = (a && isEmpty) || !b;`

Comment: @ItamarG3 please ignore initial values of `a`, `b` and `result`. It'll be at run time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `a` is `true`, you must check that `isEmpty` AND `!b` are both `true`. If `a` is `false` (or `!a` is `true`), it's enough to check that `!b` is `true`.

Therefore you can replace the logic of the if statement with:

```
result = !b && (isEmpty || !a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator:

```
result = a ? isEmpty && !b : !b;
```

Comment: "The same" but in one statement, so this is a valid solution @SFasda

Comment: @AxelH in ternary operator there are two checks like `if-else`. I want o avoid that. My question was misleading. sorry for that.

Comment: In a ternary and even in an `if-else`, there is only one condition checked, it is not doing a `if(condition) else (!condition)`. Remember that sometimes, it is better to keep the code readable @SFasda

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are searching for is the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java)

In fact, you could summarize that if-else statement with something like this (but without the println):

`result = (a ? isEmpty && !b : !b);
 System.out.println(result + "\n");`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
result = a ? isEmpty && !b : !b;
```